# Breadcumbs en Angular5

Tags: angular

Quiero poner las migas de pan , el problema es que solo me devuelve la ruta final en donde estoy, no los pasos que he ido siguiendo.

He seguido el tutorial de https://medium.com/@bo.vandersteene/angular-5-breadcrumb-c225fd9df5cf

Aunque he modificado algunas cosas:

En App-routing-modules.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ProjectListComponent,

    data: {
      breadcrumb: 'Home'
    }
  },

  {
    path: 'About',
    component: AboutComponent,

    data: {
      breadcrumb: 'About'
    }
  },
```

En el breadcrumb.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

interface BreadCrumb {
  label: string;
  url: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-breadcrumb',
  templateUrl: './breadcrumb.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./breadcrumb.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class BreadcrumbComponent implements OnInit {
  breadcrumbs$ = this.router.events
    .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .map(event => this.buildBreadCrumb(this.activatedRoute.root));
  // Build your breadcrumb starting with the root route of your current activated route

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  buildBreadCrumb(route: ActivatedRoute, url: string = '', breadcrumbs: Array<BreadCrumb> = []): Array<BreadCrumb> {
    // If no routeConfig is avalailable we are on the root path
    const label = route.routeConfig && route.routeConfig.data['breadcrumb'];
    const path = route.routeConfig ? route.routeConfig.path : '';
    // In the routeConfig the complete path is not available,
    // so we rebuild it each time
    const nextUrl = `${url}${path}/`;
    const breadcrumb = {
      label,
      url: nextUrl
    };
    const newBreadcrumbs = [...breadcrumbs, breadcrumb];
    if (route.firstChild) {
      // If we are not on our current path yet,
      // there will be more children to look after, to build our breadcumb
      return this.buildBreadCrumb(route.firstChild, nextUrl, newBreadcrumbs);
    }
    return newBreadcrumbs;
  }
}
```

Finalmente en el html:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li class="breadcrumb-item" *ngFor="let breadcrumb of breadcrumbs$ | async">
    <a [routerLink]="[breadcrumb.url]">
      {{ breadcrumb.label }}
    </a>

  </li>
</ol>
```

El problema es que si estoy en el About que viene del home. solo muestra About y no pinta el /home/About

Comment: Has *roto* la jerarquía de las rutas y por eso no te pone Home: About un es un *hijo* suyo.

Comment: Sé que tú lo tienes claro, pero llevo apenas 2 semanas, hago lo que veo por internet, podrías ser más claro por favor ?

Comment: Claro, es que estaba muy liado a primera hora como para ponerme con ello... ahora te explico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si nos fijamos en tus rutas de navegación:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ProjectListComponent,

    data: {
      breadcrumb: 'Home'
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'About',
    component: AboutComponent,

    data: {
      breadcrumb: 'About'
    }
  },
   ...
]
```

Tienes dos rutas totalmente independientes, no hay relación entre ellas. El componente que genera el *breadcrump* lo que hace es mirar los datos del componente a cargar en la ruta y los datos de sus *padres*.

Por tanto, podrías hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', //Ruta raíz
    component: ProjectListComponent,
    data: {
      breadcrumb: 'Home'
    },
    children: [
      { 
        path: 'About',
        component: AboutComponent ,
        data: {
          breadcrumb: 'About'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

De este modo, anidas las rutas y los componentes: todos son hijos de "/" (porque todos sus paths son "/" + algo).

Comment: y para mostrarlo en el html ,ya lo hace el código que tengo ?? Gracias por la explicación.

Comment: No he usado ese componente, pero tiene pinta de que es así